# How to set permissions for internal users to upload and import excel files into attendance module of Odoo 13?

Tags: excel, file-upload, module, odoo, user-permissions

Currently, My internal user (Khanh Nguyen) has choosen administration is blank.

[image: Internal User]

I would like to upload and import excel files into attendance module of Odoo 13 by internal user but only administrator can upload excel files.

[image: File log of Odoo 13]

So how to set permissions for internal user to upload and import excel files into attendance module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This trouble is due to XLSX files mistaken as SVG files. Edit odoo/fields.py following this commit

https://github.com/odoo-dev/odoo/commit/5a7a362188473de919cd7562996057f73deb5eaf

Or pull the latest Odoo 13 source, they committed this fixing days ago

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/65d709c9ab386d646f682c494cfb21cb06ec8034

Answer (score 0):

SVG file format is a kind of dangerous format when uploading it on a server because it allows to run arbitrary code (https://blog.online-convert.com/svg-file-and-its-danger/)

Such file upload is blocked in Odoo (https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/1be50fdeafcd2b94f7b2f47d6e5bc4b6ebaceadd)

Are you trying to import the employee image or do you have specific code that adds a binary field in attendance model?

As SVG import is not allowed, try with another image format like PNG or JPG that are known to work in Odoo.

Best,

Comment: No, I imported the attendance list by EXCEL FILE. I can successfully import that by using administrator account. But cannot do that with internal user.

Comment: yes, only members with "settings" privileges can upload SVG into Odoo. Can you please share a part of the Excel file you are using?

Comment: Yes, I see. But if you set that, the internal user can use the APPS and SETTINGS modules. And they can install or setup other Apps and control the SETTINGS. Cause I don't want the internal user can control with that 2 modules. That is the reason I selected the Administration of internal user is: blank or Access Right at the first time.

Comment: of course you don't want your users to be administrators. I think the issue comes from the file you are importing. Can you share a part of it please?

Comment: You can see my answer below! Or I can send you my excel file via your email. Please provide your email address. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My attendance list by excel file is just following the Odoo's format like that:

[image]

And after I imported the file. I got the information like that:

[image]

And the log file inform like that:

[image]